# Heroku PHP document root issues

Tags: php, heroku

I have a PHP app on heroku, which was deployed without issues as the following repository structure:

```
myapp
├── connect.php
├── elec.php
├── index.php
└── key.php
```

I cloned the app on a different machine, and reorganised the app as follows:

```
myapp
├── auth-server
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── connect.php
│   ├── election.php
│   ├── index.php
│   └── key.php
├── poll-server
└── Procfile
```

with the Procfile containing the following:

> web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 auth-server/

However, the deployement fails with the following message:

```
Enumerating objects: 35, done.
Counting objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 58.78 KiB | 2.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Application not supported by this buildpack!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'heroku/php' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a PHP codebase.
remote:  !
remote:  !     A PHP app on Heroku requires a 'composer.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure, or an 'index.php' for legacy behavior.
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a PHP application, ensure that one
remote:  !     of these files is present at the top level directory.
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
remote:
remote:
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to myapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

Since I have both, index.php and composer.json, at the document root specified by the Procfile, the error message does not seem to provide accurate information on what's missing.

Further, I checked out the commit that worked on the previous machine (which is also the current deployed version) only to find it now failing with the same message as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/326#issuecomment-467557798
The devs answered on the issue I created on the official GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the php written inside the file using vi command for composer.json and clone php-getting-started git repository in case.